# How to make sure my Android app runs on Intel phones?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, intel

The Android phone [Intel AZ210](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_AZ210) has an Intel CPU, and apparently [30% of Google Play's apps fail at running on it](http://crave.cnet.co.uk/mobiles/orange-san-diego-intel-phone-wont-run-third-of-android-apps-50008120/).

What steps should I take to make sure my app runs fine on such Intel-powered devices?
I guess I should refrain from using JNI, for a first?

Note: I don't have such a phone to perform tests.

Comment: It's fine to use JNI, you just cannot reference libraries that were compiled for ARM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app runs on [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) that will be a pretty clear indicator it will run on an Intel CPU. You can simply install it with VirtualBox or other VM host.

Comment: Problem: ISO are only available for a few pieces of hardware (eepc/M1400/Ideapad/tx2500/...) http://www.android-x86.org/download The first ISO (which seems to be the most generic even though it says Asus, which I don't have) runs but no network adapter.

Comment: Rather than developing first and then testing, are there guidelines I could follow to make sure my app will run on Intel phones, from the design phase?

Comment: If you don't use any native libraries and can stick to Java libraries known to work on Android then you should be fine to start. Nothing beats testing on the real thing, as any mobile dev will tell you though.